# Assigning default value for type

Tags: oracle, postgresql, user-defined-functions, postgresql-9.2, optional-parameters

How to assign default value to following type of Oracle statement into PostgreSQL 9.3?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION(....
...
DECLARE
 v_var Table01.column01%TYPE := 'SLOW';
BEGIN
...
...
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres allows to provide **parameter defaults**, which kick in for missing parameters in the function call. Only allowed for parameters *at the end of the list*.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (
                  param1 int
                , v_char tbl01.col01%TYPE DEFAULT 'foo')
...
-- no need to DECLARE anything else.
BEGIN
...
```

Syntactical shortcut would be `v_char tbl01.col01%TYPE` **`=`** `'foo'`.

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo(1, 'bar');
SELECT * FROM foo(1);        -- Param default kicks in
```

[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)