# Dynamic SELECT INTO in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, stored-functions

How can I write a dynamic `SELECT INTO` query inside a PL/pgSQL function in Postgres?

Say I have a variable called `tb_name` which is filled in a `FOR` loop from `information_schema.tables`. Now I have a variable called `tc` which will be taking the row count for each table. I want something like the following:

```
FOR tb_name in select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='some_schema' and table_name like '%1%'
LOOP
EXECUTE FORMAT('select count(*) into' || tc 'from' || tb_name);
END LOOP
```

What should be the data type of `tb_name` and `tc` in this case?

Comment: See the examples in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(_tbl_pattern text, _schema text = 'public')
  RETURNS void  -- or whatever you want to return
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tb_name information_schema.tables.table_name%TYPE;  -- currently varchar
   _tc      bigint;  -- count() returns bigint
BEGIN
   FOR _tb_name IN
      SELECT table_name
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE  table_schema = _schema
      AND    table_name   ~ _tbl_pattern  -- see below!
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I', _schema, _tb_name)
      INTO _tc;      

      -- do something with _tc
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

#### Notes

- I prepended all parameters and variables with an underscore (`_`) to avoid **naming** collisions with table columns. Just a useful convention.
- `_tc` should be **`bigint`**, since that's what the aggregate function `count()` returns.
- The data type of `_tb_name` is derived from its parent column dynamically: `information_schema.tables.table_name`**`%TYPE`**. See the chapter [*Copying Types* in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE).
- Are you sure you only want tables listed in `information_schema.tables`? Makes sense, but be aware of implications. See:

  - [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- [a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998984/dynamic-select-into-in-postgresql-function-or-stored-procedure#comment78958480_45998984) already [pointed to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE) and [Andy provided a code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46009642/939860). This is how you **assign** a single row or value returned from a dynamic query with `EXECUTE` to a (row) variable. A *single* column (like `count` in the example) is decomposed from the row type automatically, so we can assign to the scalar variable `tc` directly - in the same way we would assign a whole row to a record or row variable. Related:

  - [How to get the value of a dynamically generated field name in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808133/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-dynamically-generated-field-name-in-pl-pgsql/39812325#39812325)
- **Schema-qualify** the table name in the dynamic query. There may be other tables of the same name in the current `search_path`, which would result in completely wrong (and very confusing!) results without schema-qualification. Sneaky bug! Or *this* schema is not in the `search_path` at all, which would make the function raise an exception immediately.

  - [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)
- *Always* **quote identifiers** properly to defend against SQL injection and random errors. Schema and table have to be quoted *separately*! See:

  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
  - [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)
- I use the **regular expression operator `~`** in `table_name ~ _tbl_pattern` instead of `table_name LIKE ('%' || _tbl_pattern || '%')`, that's simpler. Be wary of special characters in the pattern parameter either way! See:

  - [PostgreSQL Reverse LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738114/postgresql-reverse-like/45740280#45740280)
  - [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)
  - [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- I set a default for the schema name in the function call: `_schema text = 'public'`. Just for convenience, you may or may not want that. See:

  - [Assigning default value for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409055/assigning-default-value-for-type/19410877#19410877)

---

Addressing [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998984/dynamic-select-into-in-pl-pgsql-function/46009971?noredirect=1#comment79023656_46009971): to pass ***values***, use the `USING` clause like:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I
                WHERE some_column = $1', _schema, _tb_name,column_name)
USING user_def_variable;
```

Related:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)

Comment: EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I', _schema, _tb_name) how can i use a where condition in this select? like EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I WHERE some_column=user_def_variable ', _schema, _tb_name,column_name)

Comment: @Karthik: I appended an answer. Please remember to ask questions as *question*. Comments are not the place.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the `%I` placeholder for `FORMAT` so that it treats your variable as an *identifier*. Also, the `INTO` clause should go **outside** the prepared statement.

```
FOR tb_name in select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='some_schema' and table_name like '%1%'
LOOP
  EXECUTE FORMAT('select count(*) from %I', tb_name) INTO tc;
END LOOP
```

Comment: It would be a sneaky bug to use the table name without schema-qualification. I added some explanation.